# multitouch gestures thinkpad x240

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, multi-touch, gestures, touchegg

I have a problem with multitouch on my thinkpad x240 (Ubuntu 16.04, Unity). I have tried touchegg with no results. Geis shows that my touchpad can recognize only two fingers. But according to tech spec this touchpad supports 5 fingers recognition. According to xinput it supports at least 3 fingers recognition. I would appreciate any help.